# C# how to close application immediately .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to close my application immediately if the user chooses a folder that does not contain the file I am looking for. My code reaches Application.Exit() but after it runs the line the application continues to run and reaches code that causes it to crash.

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (DialogResult.OK == dlg.ShowDialog())
        {
            particleFolder = dlg.SelectedPath + "\\";
            if(!(File.Exists(particleFolder + "particle.png")))
            {
                Application.Exit();
                return;

            }

        }
....
```

Comment: You should move that from the constructor to `Main()` so that you can simply `return;`.

Comment: You cannot use Application.Exit() when it did not start yet, your Program.cs file contains Application.Run() and it will happen next.  It is not the only problem, a dialog requires an owner and it doesn't have one yet.  Significantly increasing the odds that your main window disappears behind another app's window.  At best this code can appear in the Shown event handler, a File + Open command is of course boilerplate.

Answer (score 6):

[`Application.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is graceful. It sends a message to each window to close them allowing them to run any clean up logic.

[`Environment.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not graceful, so you'll die right there and then.